# Laravel Eloquent model events on created user

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent, profile

I'm trying to automatically create a profile for a user when a user is created.

I'm using the `created` event and overriding the `boot()` method. But I when call the `create()` method on `user->profile->create()`, it says create was called on null. I checked and profile is null in this.

Here's the code:

```php
static::created(function ($user) {
    // it returns profile as null, thus create() can't be used on null.
    $user->profile->create(['title' => $user->username,]);
});
```

Can anyone help me understand this? It's working in my tutor's code, and he is using Laravel 5.8 but I have version 7.1.

Comment: there is difference between `$user->profile` vs `$user->profile()`. What you want to use is  `$user->profile()->create(['title' => $user->username])`.

Comment: Thanks man, it was a silly mistake. I'm actually new to laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$user->profile` returns the related model if any exists. You have to do `$user->profile()` which returns a query builder to query the relation. Try to do it like so:

```
$user->profile()->create(['title' => $user->username,]);
```

Comment: It's working, thanks !! i also tried this, `Profile::create(['title' => $user->username, 'user_id' => $user->id]);` but i like way it was.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If I was helpful, try to mark the answer so it helps the others.